# importing private key stub from piv card into gpg on another pc

Tags: gnupg, yubikey

Sorry for puzzling terminology, I'm very new to field and it's really hard to me to orient in these new things. (maybe, probably, there isn't 'private key stub' I just saw that term used somewhere, maybe fetch retrieves only public key and we refer to that info, I don't know. Please correct me)

I don't want to private key to lay around on my hdd, so I got myself yubikey, and followed this [link](https://www.engineerbetter.com/blog/yubikey-ssh/): so I setup pins (`gpg --change-pin`), setup gpg-agent, generated key-pair on device via `gpg --card-edit`. After that, I can issue `gpg --list-secret` and see that gpg knows about generated key, and can use `ssh-add -L` to print public key. On *this* machine it works, I can say successfully push/pull from github using this pair. Great.

Now second computer. I setup gpg agent, I can see the public key using `ssh-add -L`, but that's it. I see the card and some stuff on it using `gpg --card-status`, I tried to do `gpg --edit-card`  and issued commend `fetch` (prints nothing), but gpg still does not know about existence of private key. `gpg --list-keys` and `gpg --list-secret-keys` returns nothing. From what I read both of these should make somehow private key *kinda* available in gpg (while it's actually stub and private key should be still on card).

I need somehow to get that private key representation to gpg on that second computes, so that if I do git-crypt unlock, it can find *some* key, with which I can ulock the repo.

UPDATE: Both of these PCs are fedora. Key was generated on fedora 33, I'm trying to import it into fedora 35. If I do the same on ubuntu, fetch command in `gpg --card edit` prints, that there is new key to be imported, but without ID, so it is skipping it.

UPDATE2: but surprisingly, from mentioned ubuntu, while there is no keys/secretkeys reported by gpg, I can login to f35 machine using that key on card: `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ForwardAgent=yes <f35IP>`. SO the key IS there, gpg-agent sees it, and it can be used. Totally confused.

UPDATE 3: I also tried to publish the key to some public server using `gpg --keyserver keys.openpgp.org --send-key <X>`, but if I try to retrieve it: `gpg --recv-keys <X>` is also complaints about missing user ID. What is even user ID?

Can anyone advice what to do?

Comment: Provided that you followed proper procedure and that the private key is indeed stored on the device, `gpg --card-status` should be enough to create "stubs" on your computer, that point to the device. `fetch` requires a valid URL where the public key can be retrieved. But the public key can also be imported from a regular file instead... (may actually be easier) [This](https://steemit.com/security/@sneak/openpgp-smartcard-secret-key-stub-recovery) may help too.

Comment: I kinda figured it out, yet I'd be grateful if you can shed some light on it. I tried more keyservers and this one worked for me: keyserver.ubuntu.com. `fetch` didn't work probably because there isn't public key url specified. And `gpg --recv-keys <X>` didn't work because other keyservers  does not have set user id for some reason. 1.WHY they do that? 2. how to make other keyservers work as well?  3. how to --recv-keys without public id? 4. what is actually stored on card, if we have to fetch public key from 3rd party? Just private key and some hash of public key? I don't understand that.weird

Comment: @Kate ^^ I understand this is too many questions, but the problem causing issue in this question was  missing public key in gpg / unability to fetch it from `--keyserver keys.openpgp.org` because of unset public id. I have it resolved by luck, but I feel that I don't understand the argumentation why is all of this happening. Please if you have some time, having this explained in answer would help me greatly, and others as well.